# How to extend js class from outside library in TypeScript / Using mojs in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i know how to declare library ( example usage mojs):

```
declare var mojs:any;
```

but i have problem with extending from it:

```
class MyObject extends mojs.CustomShape {
    getShape () {
      return '..path'
    }
  };
```

i get error:

> Type 'any' is not constructor object type

I tried something like this:

```
declare var mojs:Object{

 CustomShape:any
};
```

but no luck - it is wrong code.

So how can I extend js library class in typescript?

Comment: Have you searched for the definition file for this library in `DefinitelyTyped` or `typings`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer i work with typescript from yestarday, so more information please.

Comment: @MaciejSikora: You say you've just started. Is that because you're new to the project using it, or because you're *adding* it to a project? If the latter, you might consider whether you really need typescript at all, as opposed to the features of ES2015+.

Comment: Typescript has definition files (`.d.ts` files) which are kinda like the C/C++ h files. They don't have any implementation in them, just describe the types, classes, interfaces and so on. You can read about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html). But for used libraries you can find existing definition files and there are a few services for that such as `typings` and `DefinitelyTyped`

Comment: I do not see this lib in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i write Javascript for many years, wanted to check out this nice tool, but this problem is very annoying

Comment: Hi! Sorry about that. I never used the TypeScript too much but it works as expected for me http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/6be48d556d45771369f03865ef4f022a?editors=0010 , maybe some config error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i managed this by setting type as **ObjectConstructor**

My code for mojs:

```
declare var mojs: {
    CustomShape:ObjectConstructor, //here usage
    addShape:any,
    Burst:any,
    Timeline:any,
    Shape:any,
    ShapeSwirl:any
};
```

So with ObjectConstructor i can extend this class without errors like:

```
 class MyObject extends mojs.CustomShape {
   getShape () {
    return '..path'
   }
 };
```