# ionic ts part to can't correctly put JavaScript

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm try to create like this  [example animated](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQoqjg) for my Ionic mobile application,
I have small issue  , actually this animated part not working for me, anyone know know how to put that script part correctly for Ionic, 
Please help me to fix that issue 
Thanks

this is my code sample [my live code part without animated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1jzvrq)

this is my code

**html**

```
<div class="claps">
  <button id="clap" class="clap">
  <span>
    <!--  SVG Created by Luis Durazo from the Noun Project  -->
    <svg id="clap--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-549 338 100.1 125">
  <path d="M-471.2 366.8c1.2 1.1 1.9 2.6 2.3 4.1.4-.3.8-.5 1.2-.7 1-1.9.7-4.3-1-5.9-2-1.9-5.2-1.9-7.2.1l-.2.2c1.8.1 3.6.9 4.9 2.2zm-28.8 14c.4.9.7 1.9.8 3.1l16.5-16.9c.6-.6 1.4-1.1 2.1-1.5 1-1.9.7-4.4-.9-6-2-1.9-5.2-1.9-7.2.1l-15.5 15.9c2.3 2.2 3.1 3 4.2 5.3zm-38.9 39.7c-.1-8.9 3.2-17.2 9.4-23.6l18.6-19c.7-2 .5-4.1-.1-5.3-.8-1.8-1.3-2.3-3.6-4.5l-20.9 21.4c-10.6 10.8-11.2 27.6-2.3 39.3-.6-2.6-1-5.4-1.1-8.3z"/>
  <path d="M-527.2 399.1l20.9-21.4c2.2 2.2 2.7 2.6 3.5 4.5.8 1.8 1 5.4-1.6 8l-11.8 12.2c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l34-35c1.9-2 5.2-2.1 7.2-.1 2 1.9 2 5.2.1 7.2l-24.7 25.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l28.5-29.3c2-2 5.2-2 7.1-.1 2 1.9 2 5.1.1 7.1l-28.5 29.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.4 1.7 0l24.7-25.3c1.9-2 5.1-2.1 7.1-.1 2 1.9 2 5.2.1 7.2l-24.7 25.3c-.5.5-.4 1.2 0 1.7.5.5 1.2.5 1.7 0l14.6-15c2-2 5.2-2 7.2-.1 2 2 2.1 5.2.1 7.2l-27.6 28.4c-11.6 11.9-30.6 12.2-42.5.6-12-11.7-12.2-30.8-.6-42.7m18.1-48.4l-.7 4.9-2.2-4.4m7.6.9l-3.7 3.4 1.2-4.8m5.5 4.7l-4.8 1.6 3.1-3.9"/>
</svg>
  </span>
  <span id="clap--count" class="clap--count"></span>
  <span id="clap--count-total" class="clap--count-total"></span>
</button>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
  $btn-dimension: 80px;
    $primary-color: rgba(189,195,199 ,1);
    $secondary-color: rgba(39,174,96 ,1);
    @mixin debug {
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }



    /*========================
        BASIC styles
      =======================*/
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    .claps {margin-top: 10rem;margin-left: 5rem;}
    /*========================
        BUTTON styles
      =======================*/
    .clap {
      position: relative;
      outline: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid $primary-color;
      width: $btn-dimension;
      height: $btn-dimension; 
      background: none;
      &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        //border: 1px solid $primary-color;
        width: $btn-dimension - 1px;
        height: $btn-dimension - 1px;
      }
      &:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
       border: 1px solid $secondary-color;
       transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in;
        &:after {
          animation: shockwave 1s ease-in infinite;
        } 
      }
      svg {
        width: 40px;
        fill: none;
        stroke: $secondary-color;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        &.checked {
          fill: $secondary-color;
          stroke: #fff;
          stroke-width: 1px;
        }
      }
      .clap--count {
        position: absolute;
        top: -$btn-dimension/1.6;
        left: $btn-dimension/4;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        color: white;
        background: $secondary-color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: $btn-dimension/2;
        width: $btn-dimension/2;
        line-height: $btn-dimension/2;
      }
      .clap--count-total {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        width: $btn-dimension;
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        top: -$btn-dimension/3.5;
        color: $primary-color; 
      }
    }



    /*====================
            Message
    ======================*/
    #message {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      color: $secondary-color;
      line-height: 1.52rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      font-size: 0.9rem;
      a {
        color: $primary-color
      }
    }
@keyframes shockwave {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px $secondary-color;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px darken($secondary-color, 20%), inset 0 0 10px $secondary-color;
  }
}
```

---

I want to know how to put this part correctly for Ionic

```
const clap = document.getElementById('clap')
const clapIcon = document.getElementById('clap--icon')
const clapCount = document.getElementById('clap--count')
const clapTotalCount = document.getElementById('clap--count-total')
const initialNumberOfClaps = generateRandomNumber(500, 10000);
const btnDimension = 80
const tlDuration = 300
let numberOfClaps = 0
let clapHold;

const triangleBurst = new mojs.Burst({
  parent: clap,
  radius: {50:95},
  count: 5,
  angle: 30,
  children: {
    shape: 'polygon',
    radius: {6: 0},
    scale: 1,
    stroke: 'rgba(211,84,0 ,0.5)',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    angle: 210,
    delay: 30,
    speed: 0.2,
    easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3 ,1),
    duration: tlDuration
  } 
})
const circleBurst = new mojs.Burst({
  parent: clap,
  radius: {50:75},
  angle: 25,
  duration: tlDuration,
  children: {
    shape: 'circle',
    fill: 'rgba(149,165,166 ,0.5)',
    delay: 30,
    speed: 0.2,
    radius: {3: 0},
    easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3, 1),
  }
})
const countAnimation = new mojs.Html({
  el: '#clap--count',
  isShowStart: false,
  isShowEnd: true,
  y: {0: -30},
  opacity: {0:1},
  duration: tlDuration
}).then({
  opacity: {1:0},
  y: -80,
  delay: tlDuration/2
})
const countTotalAnimation = new mojs.Html({
  el: '#clap--count-total',
  isShowStart: false,
  isShowEnd: true,
  opacity: {0:1},
  delay: 3*(tlDuration)/2,
  duration: tlDuration,
  y: {0: -3}
})
const scaleButton = new mojs.Html({
  el: '#clap',
  duration: tlDuration,
  scale: {1.3: 1},
  easing: mojs.easing.out
})
clap.style.transform = "scale(1, 1)" /*Bug1 fix*/

const animationTimeline = new mojs.Timeline()
animationTimeline.add([
  triangleBurst,
  circleBurst,
  countAnimation,
  countTotalAnimation,
  scaleButton
])


clap.addEventListener('click', function() {
   repeatClapping();
})

clap.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
   clapHold = setInterval(function() {
   repeatClapping();
   }, 400)
})

clap.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
 clearInterval(clapHold);
})


function repeatClapping() {
 updateNumberOfClaps()
 animationTimeline.replay()
 clapIcon.classList.add('checked')
}

function updateNumberOfClaps() {
  numberOfClaps < 50 ? numberOfClaps++ : null
  clapCount.innerHTML = "+" + numberOfClaps
  clapTotalCount.innerHTML = initialNumberOfClaps + numberOfClaps
}

function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Comment: Initially I would start with implementing functionality, like clapping count increases when user clicks.  simple [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pmzppf?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov sir, your solution is really appreciate, but whers is the put animated part  like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQoqjg

Comment: It uses mojs library, you will need to import it, see [here how to import js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833895/how-to-include-js-file-in-ionic-3). And then you will rewrite js file in `angular` style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create dedicated component like `clap`

But first you need to add `mojs` to your page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mo-js/0.288.1/mo.min.js"></scrip>
```

Since we don't have typings for mojs you can just define it as `any`:

```typescript
declare let mojs: any;
```

(Note: you can create typings something like [How to extend js class from outside library in TypeScript / Using mojs in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632062/how-to-extend-js-class-from-outside-library-in-typescript-using-mojs-in-typesc) if you want)

Now it's time to create our custom component.

We're going to use `ViewChild` instead of `document.getElementById` to hold of reference to DOM element. For that we need to put template references on elements (`<button #clap`). We will use that references instead of selectors like `el: '#clap--count-total',` so our component will be scope safed

Also we won't listen to dom events through `.addEventListener` but rather via element output events like `(click)`

So here's the code

**clap.component.html**

```typescript
<button #clap class="clap"
     (click)="repeatClapping()" 
     (mousedown)="onClapMouseDown()" 
     (mouseup)="onClapMouseUp()">
  <span>
    <svg [class.checked]="clapIconChecked" ...>
      ...
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span #clapCount class="clap--count">+{{currentClaps}}</span>
  <span #clapCountTotal class="clap--count-total">{{claps}}</span>
</button>
```

**clap.component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

declare let mojs: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'clap',
  templateUrl: './clap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clap.component.css']
})
export class ClapComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() claps = 0;

  @Input() tlDuration = 300;

  @Output() clapsChange = new EventEmitter();

  @ViewChild('clap') clapEl: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('clapCount') clapCountEl: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('clapCountTotal') clapCountTotalEl: ElementRef;

  currentClaps: number = 0;

  clapIconChecked = false;

  private animationTimeline: any;

  private clapHold: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    const triangleBurst = new mojs.Burst({
      parent: this.clapEl.nativeElement,
      radius: {50: 95},
      count: 5,
      angle: 30,
      children: {
        shape: 'polygon',
        radius: {6: 0},
        scale: 1,
        stroke: 'rgba(211,84,0 ,0.5)',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        angle: 210,
        delay: 30,
        speed: 0.2,
        easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3, 1),
        duration: this.tlDuration
      }
    });

    const circleBurst = new mojs.Burst({
      parent: this.clapEl.nativeElement,
      radius: {50: 75},
      angle: 25,
      duration: this.tlDuration,
      children: {
        shape: 'circle',
        fill: 'rgba(149,165,166 ,0.5)',
        delay: 30,
        speed: 0.2,
        radius: {3: 0},
        easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3, 1),
      }
    });

    const countAnimation = new mojs.Html({
      el: this.clapCountEl.nativeElement,
      isShowStart: false,
      isShowEnd: true,
      y: {0: -30},
      opacity: {0: 1},
      duration: this.tlDuration
    }).then({
      opacity: {1: 0},
      y: -80,
      delay: this.tlDuration / 2
    });

    const countTotalAnimation = new mojs.Html({
      el: this.clapCountTotalEl.nativeElement,
      isShowStart: false,
      isShowEnd: true,
      opacity: {0: 1},
      delay: 3 * (this.tlDuration) / 2,
      duration: this.tlDuration,
      y: {0: -3}
    });

    const scaleButton = new mojs.Html({
      el: this.clapEl.nativeElement,
      duration: this.tlDuration,
      scale: {1.3: 1},
      easing: mojs.easing.out
    });

    this.clapEl.nativeElement.style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';

    this.animationTimeline = new mojs.Timeline();
    this.animationTimeline.add([
      triangleBurst,
      circleBurst,
      countAnimation,
      countTotalAnimation,
      scaleButton
    ]);
  } 

  repeatClapping() {
    if (this.currentClaps > 49) {
      alert('Limit 50 claps');
      return;
    }

    this.currentClaps++;
    this.claps++;
    this.clapsChange.emit(this.claps);

    this.animationTimeline.replay();
    this.clapIconChecked = true;
  }

  onClapMouseDown() {
    this.clapHold = setInterval(() => {
      this.repeatClapping();
    }, 400);
  }

  onClapMouseUp() {
    clearInterval(this.clapHold);
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no magic here. It's simple component with two-way binding that we can use anywhere as follows:

**home.html**

```typescript
<clap [(claps)]="claps"></clap>
```

**home.ts**

```typescript
export class HomePage {
  claps = generateRandomNumber(500, 10000);
}

function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

[image]

Try it out **[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/zid3Do5mGNPUwTEE48fu?open=app%2Fclap%2Fclap.component.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: Sir ,I  face the some error , `Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'generateRandomNumber'.


  claps = generateRandomNumber(500, 10000);`

Comment: I moved `generateRandomNumber` to `home.ts` https://ng-run.com/edit/zid3Do5mGNPUwTEE48fu?open=app%2Fpages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts&layout=1

Comment: i added that part, but display error `Typescript Error Cannot find name 'generateRandomNumber'. claps = generateRandomNumber(500, 10000); `

Comment: this is my added code part  `export class SupportPage {


  claps = generateRandomNumber(500, 10000);
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public viewCtrl: ViewController) {

    function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

  }`

Comment: Function should be outside of class. Or you can use method like https://ng-run.com/edit/I0WASt0PdRT4pxrji4cb?open=app%2Fpages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts&layout=1

Comment: Sir ,can you please check it, its not work for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tkgtjz

Comment: It won't work in stackblitz. mojs creates `div` inside body to calculate some parameters but stackblitz removes this `div` And you made mistake when changing index.html

Comment: Here's plunker version https://plnkr.co/edit/r7LJNtRhfIlF9BEUI6Mo?p=preview Notice that I added script inside body because mojs tries insert div inside body and if we add mojs in head there is no body tag yet

Comment: sir now  my error  is `Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: mojs is not defined
ReferenceError: mojs is not defined`, I added `mojs` for  index .html

Comment: Do you get this error In stackblitz? I said it won't work there. See my two demos

Comment: no sir , I get that error for my an Ionic project >  home page

Comment: Did you add it inside body?

Comment: yeah I added  index.html to

Comment: Can you share your repository?

Comment: sir now its working, my mistake im add ` mojs` to header tag, now i added inside the body its working fine

Comment: Sir thanks for your valuable time and again thanks for the guide me

Comment: You can take the bounty for after 8hours